# Firebase ANR - Not even using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-anr-dialog

With recent updates to GMS, a new ANR has been introduced. If you exit the app, and then return, that's when the ANR is initialized. The thread trace seems to point to Firebase, but I never even started using Firebase. I guess it must be part of the new GMS package?

> 06-11 00:34:00.143: E/ActivityManager(1487): ANR in com.myapp
>
> 06-11 00:34:00.143: E/ActivityManager(1487): PID: 19700
>
> 06-11 00:34:00.143: E/ActivityManager(1487): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT flg=0x14 cmp=com.myapp/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver (has extras) }

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.mindscapehq.android:raygun4android:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
}
```

And my emulator has Play Services 9.+

Comment: should post your gradle file content in the question

Comment: See my edits for dependencies.

Comment: @CommonsWare , you always have good insight. I really need some right now.

Comment: It sounds like there might be a very rare problem.  Do you think it's the same as this?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/Z4vqS1Ml3N4/edIlaFB6AwAJ  If so, could you please also file a bug at the URL I show at the end of that discussion?

Comment: I think it's exactly the same as that. Thanks.

Comment: 09-11 11:09:35.347 1699 1748 E ActivityManager: ANR in com.google.android.apps.messaging 
09-11 11:09:35.347 1699 1748 E ActivityManager: PID: 1233 
09-11 11:09:35.347 1699 1748 E ActivityManager: Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT flg=0x14 cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver (has extras) }

I am seeing this logs. Android Messages hangs forever after kill and reopen. Any lead on this ? Recently i updated my Android Messages to v2.4.036 via PlayStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap this up, there was a problem in Google Play services 9.6.80.  It was fixed in 9.6.83.  Likely no one is seeing this problem any more as Play has gone through the 9.8.x release cycle successfully and pretty much all devices should be updated.